# How to set a hidden value to jsf backing bean from view

Tags: jsf

I am having a hard-coded value that needs to be set to the jsf backing bean on form submit.

Can any one tell this please.

```
 <h:inputHidden value="#{leaveBean.fApproverEmail}"></h:inputHidden>
```

but i want to send a hard coded value inplace of `"#{leaveBean.fApproverEmail}"` and set it to a property of backing bean..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Option 1.

Have your property initialized to your hardcoded value. JSF will auto-update this property on form submit. So, in case it has changed you will end up with a renewed property value in your action method.

```
String fApproverEmail = "default";

<h:inputHidden id="app" value="#{leaveBean.fApproverEmail}" />
```

### Option 2.

Have a plain HTML `<input type="hidden">` or valueless `<h:inputHidden>`. This way the submitted value is available in request parameter map. So you'll be able to grab it from `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()` with its name as the key. But beware that in case your object's not a string you'll have to do conversion/validation on your own and action method is a wrong place to put that logic.

```
String fApproverEmail;
public void action() {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    String s1 = ec.getRequestParameterMap().get("plain");
    String s2 = ec.getRequestParameterMap().get("form:jsf");
    fApproverEmail = ...;//and-or other logic
}

<h:form id="form">
    <h:inputHidden id="jsf" />
    <input type="hidden" id="plain" name="plain" value="#{backingBean.fApproverEmail}"/>
    ...
</h:form>
```

Comment: Please rollback your edit and press *Ask question* button to ask a new question. Things are not to be done this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the bean method directly from your h:inputHidden tag, this way you can use another bean method to get the value you need.

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{leaveBean.fApproverEmail(otherBean.methodOrProperty)}"/>
```